# Реализация переключения между серверами в android приложении

Tags: java, android, rest

Имеется программа, в которой пользователю можно будет переключаться между серверами. Есть класс, отвечающий за финализированную строку с путем (адресом) для подключения. Имеется макет и класс, где реализован Spinner и его адаптер соответственно. Как можно установить например switch / case таким образом, чтобы переменная получала необходимо значение по выбранному серверу ?
P.S. Ретрофит уже реализован и требует наличие именно константной переменной.

Класс с "путем":

```
public class AppProperties {

    private static String pIdentificator = "";

    public static final String path = "path1"; 

    public static String getpIdentificator() {
        return pIdentificator;
    }

    public static void setpIdentificator(String pInd) {
        pIdentificator = pInd;
    }
}
```

Класс с адаптером спиннера и switch / case:

```
public PresenterAuthActivity(ActivityAuth cntx) {
        authActivity = cntx;
        DataBaseInit db = new DataBaseInit();
        db.initTables();
        pg = authActivity.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        authActivity.startService(new Intent(App.getAppContext(), ServiceNetworkConnectionState.class));
        //authActivity.startForegroundService(new Intent(App.getAppContext(), ServiceNetworkConnectionState.class));
        helperBlockingScreen = new HelperBlockingScreen(authActivity, authActivity.findViewById(R.id.constrLayMain));
        helperBlockingScreen.setMainLayout(authActivity.findViewById(R.id.constrLayMain));
        ArrayList<Button> btns = new ArrayList<>();

        btns.add(authActivity.findViewById(R.id.button));
        helperBlockingScreen.setButtons(btns);
        authHanlder = new AuthHanlder(authActivity, this);
        setValuesToLogingAndPassword();

        // Spinner
        spinner = authActivity.findViewById(R.id.Spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(authActivity, R.array.Server,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                       View itemSelected, int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) {

                String[] choose = authActivity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Server);
                switch (selectedItemPosition) {
                    case 1:
                        AppProperties.path = "mobileraids_test";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        AppProperties.path = "path2";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        AppProperties.path = "path3";
                        break;
                }
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(authActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Ваш выбор: " + choose[selectedItemPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
```